# What is the notation if every element of a vector is greater than or equal to 0?

Tags: inequality, notation, vectors

If I have a vector, and I want to write that every value in the vector is greater than or equal to zero, is the following an acceptable notation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5
\end{bmatrix} \ge 0$$

If not, does someone have a recommendation?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: It is acceptable but in no way self-explanatory. It is good practice to write once and for all what it means. Translate the picture to proper MathJax. That "another example" is not acceptable. What has $|x||y|\ge 0|z|$ to do with the picture and the question ?

Comment: This is acceptable notation. It appears often in linear programming. However, if you're unsure if the reader will understand what you mean, it's never a bad idea to define the notation before you use it.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll look into MathJax, so I can copy and paste my math into the body of the comment without having to use a screenshot.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I use $x \geq 0$, but I write a comment that the inequality means that each component of $x$ is nonnegative.

Comment: Just to confirm that $x \ge 0$ is very much used in linear programming - but not much elsewhere. Also, a typical set of constraints is expressed by $Ax \le b$, where A is a (non-square) matrix. Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming which shows both.